# Transaction reverted: function returned an unexpected amount of data

Tags: solidity, uniswap

i was building a bot that should: take a flashloan from dydx (the token received from the flashloan is WETH), trade the token received on uniswap and sushiswap (WETH and COMPOUND) but When i test on remix the flashloan code alone, the code is successfull but when i test the code with the trading functions it gives me this error: `Error: Transaction reverted: function returned an unexpected amount of data` Here's the code:

```
contract Arbitrage is DyDxFlashLoan {
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uRouter;
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable sRouter;

    address public owner;

    constructor(address _uRouter, address _sRouter) payable {
        uRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_uRouter);
        sRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_sRouter);
        owner = msg.sender;
        (bool success, ) = WETH.call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(success, "fail to get weth");
    }

    function executeTrade(
        address _tokenA,
        address _tokenB,
        uint _tokensFromFlashLoan,
        bool _startOnUniswap
    ) external {
        uint balanceBefore = IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(address(this));
        console.log(balanceBefore);
        bytes memory data = abi.encode(
            _startOnUniswap,
            _tokenA,
            _tokenB,
            _tokensFromFlashLoan,
            balanceBefore
        );
        console.log("calling the flashloan function");
        flashloan(_tokenA, _tokensFromFlashLoan, data);
    }

    function callFunction(
        address,
        Info calldata,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external onlyPool {
        (
            bool _startOnUniswap,
            address _tokenA,
            address _tokenB,
            uint256 _tokensFromFlashLoan,
            uint256 balanceBefore
        ) = abi.decode(data, (bool, address, address, uint256, uint256));
        uint balanceAfter = IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(address(this));

        require(
            balanceAfter - balanceBefore == _tokensFromFlashLoan,
            "Didn't receive flash loan"
        );

        address[] memory tokens;
        if (_startOnUniswap == true) {
            tokens[0] = _tokenA;
            tokens[1] = _tokenB;

            swapOnUniswap(_tokensFromFlashLoan, 10, tokens);

            tokens[0] = _tokenB;
            tokens[1] = _tokenA;

            swapOnSushiswap(
                IERC20(tokens[0]).balanceOf(address(this)),
                10,
                tokens
            );
        } else {
            tokens[0] = _tokenA;
            tokens[1] = _tokenB;

            swapOnSushiswap(_tokensFromFlashLoan, 10, tokens);

            tokens[0] = _tokenB;
            tokens[1] = _tokenA;

            swapOnUniswap(
                IERC20(tokens[0]).balanceOf(address(this)),
                10,
                tokens
            );
        }
    }

    function swapOnUniswap(
        uint _amountIn,
        uint _amountOut,
        address[] memory _path
    ) internal {
        // swapExactTokensForTokes
        // mettiamo dentro un input token e riceviamo un output token
        // controllare se il token è effetivamente un token
        require(
            IERC20(_path[0]).approve(address(uRouter), _amountIn),
            "Uniswap failed the approval"
        );

        // swappiamo i token e li riceve lo smart contract
        uRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            _amountIn,
            _amountOut,
            _path,
            address(this),
            (block.timestamp + 1200)
        );
    }

    function swapOnSushiswap(
        uint _amountIn,
        uint _amountOut,
        address[] memory _path
    ) internal {
        require(
            IERC20(_path[0]).approve(address(sRouter), _amountIn),
            "Sushiswap failed the approval"
        );

        uRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            _amountIn,
            _amountOut,
            _path,
            address(this),
            (block.timestamp + 1200)
        );
    }
}
```

If you have any suggestion please let me know, im stuck on this bug for a week now and help would be very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The likely issue is that one of the functions you are calling has `return()` keyword in its interface (returns some data). But the implementation in your contract has no `return()` keyword.

Can you specify which function() causes this error?

Comment: The function that causes the error is the executeaTrade function

Comment: @Shadq, so what was the issue? DyDxFlashLoan had executeTrade function with return() parameter?

Comment: The issue is this line: uint balanceBefore = IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(_tokenA); that returns an unexpected amount of data but i still cannot understand why? I checked the openzepplin docs and they said that this .balanceOf() function returned an uint, but the error doesnt go away.

Answer (score 2):

I saw the peculiar behavior in another scenario, taught that I will add it for anybody's future reference.

```
contract BookRepository {
    struct Book {
        uint256 bookId;
        uint256 dueDate;
        string author;
        string name;
        address borrowed;
    }

    Book[] public books;
    ...
```

And Suppose there is an interface to this contract:

```
interface IRepo {
    function issueBook(uint256 bookId, address borrowedBy) external;

    function returnBook(uint256 bookId) external;

    function books(uint256 bookId) external returns (Book memory);
}
```

In the above scenario,
books storage variable is made public hence the solidity compiler adds the function, but its signature is not

```
function books(uint256 bookId) external returns (Book memory);
```

But instead it is

```
function book(uint256 bookId) external returns (uint256, uint256, string memory, string memory, address);
```

But the error is the same. Hope this helps. But overall it is a misappropriate implementation returns vs interface return statement. Overall the above answer is perfect. But this is just another flavor of the same error.